# Java - Enforce TextField Format - UX - 00:00:00;00

Tags: java, regex, swing, user-interface

Please see below image of the UI of my current application

[image]

Currently, I am enforcing Data Format of the text fields in the back end. If the RegEx does match (00:00:00;00), it will throw an error.

My question is from a UX perspective, is it possible to make the input for the text box usable in a way that does not require the user to input the ': : ;' characters? I am trying to accomplish functionality so they could type into the box, 10002000, and it will format as (10:00:20;00) visually on the frame.

### GUI.java

```
package xml.editor;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{

TextField startTime, durationField;
Button save;

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Parser xmlEditor;
private String startTimeValue;
private String durationValue;


// Constructor Requires FilePath
// File Path fed from Main

public GUI(String fp){
    init(fp);
}


public void init(String fp) {

    // Create the Parser

    this.setXmlEditor(new Parser(fp));

    add(new Label("Start Time"));

    // Current Values of Fields to be changed

    startTimeValue = xmlEditor.getStartTimeValue();
    durationValue = xmlEditor.getDurationValue();

    // Text Fields start with current value
    startTime = new TextField(startTimeValue);

    add(new Label("Duration"));
    durationField = new TextField(durationValue);

    save = new Button("save");
    save.addActionListener(this);


    add(startTime);
    add(durationField);
    add(save);

}

public void displayError(String error){
    /* 
     * Error Handling UI Layout
     */

    JFrame f = new JFrame(error);
    Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
    contentPane.add(new Label(error));

    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);

    //error
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{


    if(checkTextForm(startTime.getText())){
        xmlEditor.updateStartTimeValue(startTime.getText());
    }else{
        displayError("Start Time Format Error");
    }
    if(checkTextForm(durationField.getText())){
        xmlEditor.updateDurationValue(durationField.getText());
    }else{
        displayError("End Time Format Error");
    }

    if((checkTextForm(startTime.getText()) && checkTextForm(durationField.getText()))){
        System.exit(0);

    }






}

public boolean checkTextForm(String text){



    if(text.matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d;\\d\\d")){
        System.out.println("testtest");
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }


}


public Parser getXmlEditor() {
    return xmlEditor;
}

public void setXmlEditor(Parser xmlEditor) {
    this.xmlEditor = xmlEditor;
}

}
```

Please let me know if there are any suggestions where to get started, or if there is a specific object I should be using instead of TextField.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `JFormattedTextField` with `MaskFormatter`.

```
JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();     
try {
    MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##;##");
    maskFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
    maskFormatter.install(formattedTextField);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

More info at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Demo code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JFormattedTextField field1 = new JFormattedTextField();
field1.setColumns(10);
JFormattedTextField field2 = new JFormattedTextField();
field2.setColumns(10);
try {
    MaskFormatter mask1 = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##;##");
    mask1.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
    mask1.install(field1);

    MaskFormatter mask2 = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##;##");
    mask2.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
    mask2.install(field2);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
panel.add(field1);
panel.add(field2);

frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will work with the suggested objects when I finish on other project. Thanks again

Comment: is there a known consistency issue with maskFormatter? when I was testing out the implementation for my 2 fields, I found it worked perfectly, but was able to trick it and delete the mask somewhat easily a couple times.

Comment: What do you mean by remove mask. Ware you able to delete field content completely with `:` and `;`?

Comment: @Busturdust I had problems when I used same mask on two fields, but creating separate mask for each field solved it (not sure why, unfortunately I am not Swing expert).

Comment: yes delete field content completely. But this was only when actively trying to trick it, and yea I ran into the problem with 2 fields as well and did the same workaround. It's really too small a utility to really care more, but for the sake of learning id be interested to know

Comment: Actually now that I also tested this solution it seems that when I gain focus on field second time I can set whatever I want... That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I dont have access to the code right now, tomorrow at work is a new day, but if your feeling adventurous and find out anything id be happy to hear it

Comment: I tested your code a little a more, I can get it blanked it, idk what goes on

Comment: @Busturdust I am not sure what was causing this bug, but after using `maskFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');` with `new JFormattedTextField();` instead of `new JFormattedTextField("00:00:00;00");` seems to solve it (at least I wasn't able to set other format then specified with this new settings).

Comment: actually, I have values which will be displayed from default. Should i be doing something like `maskFormatter.setPlaceholderCharacter(valueVariable)`   Ill have to test tomorrow better

Comment: @Busturdust From what I see you can simply use `formattedTextField.setText("12:34:56;78");` after you `install` MaskFormatter on it.