# Python 3 Tkinter - How to Enforce a default format

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing my first Python tkinter application.

The Application itself is an xml editor. It will look for 2 elements, and update the text value of the the element. The code below is proof-of-concept, and does not actually update anything yet.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


class NameDropper(Frame):

    def __init__(self,fp=None):
        self.fp = fp
        #Create the Mainframe
        root = Tk()
        root.config(bg="red")
        root.title("NameDropper")
        mainframe = Frame(root, colormap="new")
        #mainframe.config(width=200,height=200,bg="green")

        # place and configure
        mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,W,E,S)) #makes Frame appear on screen
        #mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.mainframe = mainframe
        self.createVariables()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.gridWidgets()
        #self.mainframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

    def createVariables(self):
        self.start = StringVar()
        self.duration = StringVar()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.mainframe.startLabel = Label(self.mainframe,text="Start",font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.mainframe.startEntry = Entry(self.mainframe,textvariable=self.start,font=("Helvetica", 16))
        # self.mainframe.startLabel.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)
        self.mainframe.durLabel = Label(self.mainframe,text="Duration",font=("Helvetica", 16))
        # self.mainframe.durLabel.pack(side="left", fill=None, expand=False)
        self.mainframe.durEntry =  Entry(self.mainframe,textvariable=self.duration,font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.mainframe.saveButton = Button(self.mainframe, text='Save', command=self.save)
        self.mainframe.quitButton = Button(self.mainframe,text='Quit',command=self.mainframe.quit)

    def gridWidgets(self):
        self.mainframe.startLabel.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky=(N,W))
        # self.mainframe.startLabel.config(bg="red")
        self.mainframe.startEntry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=(N,W))
        # self.mainframe.startEntry.config(bg="black")
        self.mainframe.durLabel.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky=(N,W))
        self.mainframe.durEntry.grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(N,W))
        self.mainframe.saveButton.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky=SW)
        self.mainframe.quitButton.grid(column=2,row=3,sticky=SE)

    def save(self):
        root = ET.parse(fp).getroot()
        generic_anc_enable = root.findall('GenericANCEnable')
        for item in generic_anc_enable:
            start_element = item.find('StartTimecode')
            duration_element = item.find('DurationTimecode')
            start_element.text = str(self.mainframe.startEntry.get())
            duration_element.text = str(self.mainframe.durEntry.get())


            messagebox.showwarning(start_element.text)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    fp = "C:\\Users\\206420055\\Documents\\VancInsertionLabelTdyShwCrwlTC.xml"
    app = NameDropper(fp)

    app.mainframe.mainloop()
```

The question I have, is there any way to mask the `Entry` Fields so that they automatically and consistently abide by a certain format?

[image]

The Goal would be to have both labels Automatically follow the format `xx:yy:zz;nn`

I have previously built this application in Java a year ago, but new requirements cause me to get off Java.

The original question from Last August about the Java version is here
[Java - Enforce TextField Format - UX - 00:00:00;00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987866/java-enforce-textfield-format-ux-00000000)

I havent yet been able to find any documentation on enforcing the format

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in to the entry widget to do that. All of the basic building blocks are available to do it, but you'll have to do most of the work yourself.

A simple solution is to use four entry widgets (for xx, yy, zz and nn) with three labels (for the colons). To get fancier you can set up custom bindings to automatically insert the colons as the user types.

You can also use the entry widget validation feature to simply reject any characters that don't result in a string in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

In Flask-wtforms, there is a validation idea that would be applicable here; which is to use regex to check that the input matches certain criteria. If the inputed data doesn't match a given format of your choosing, simply reject the submition with a helpful message to the user.

```
import re

start_time = re.compile(r'^(([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)|24:00)$')
duration = re.compile('[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2};[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}')


if start_time.match(user_input_var):
    add_well_formatted_data()
else:
    print('please format the data accordingly:  xx,yy,zz,nn')

if duration.match(user_input_var):
    add_well_formatted_data()
else:
    print('please format the data accordingly:  xx,yy,zz,nn')
```

Alternatively, you shouldn't need regex for this, as there are format validators in the datetime class.